# Google Fit stopped working, "Fitness.HistoryApi.insertData" returns success but doesn't shows up in Google Fit application

Tags: android, google-fit

The code implemented in my application once worked, the data was inserted/displayed in Google Fit correctly, but now it doesn't work.

I have also tested the `BasicHistoryApi` but it doesn't work.(https://github.com/googlesamples/android-fit)
Screenshot where this test app returns no error:
[image]

Please tell me if you use this method `Fitness.HistoryApi.insertData()` and it works correctly, because I can't find any solution to make it work.

This code snippet returns "success", but no changes in my Google Fit:

```html
  DataSet runningDataSet = DataSet.create(runningDataSource);
  runningDataSet.add(runningDataSet.createDataPoint().setTimeInterval(
    startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));

  Session session = new Session.Builder().setName("TEST " + startTime)
    .setDescription("Test description")
    .setIdentifier("TEST " + " - " + startTime)
    .setActivity(FitnessActivities.RUNNING_JOGGING)
    .setStartTime(startTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .setEndTime(endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).build();

  SessionInsertRequest insertRequest = new SessionInsertRequest.Builder()
    .setSession(session).addDataSet(runningDataSet).build();

  Log.i(TAG, "Inserting the session in the History API");
  com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status insertStatus = Fitness.SessionsApi
    .insertSession(MainActivity.getFitnessClient(), insertRequest)
    .await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

  if (!insertStatus.isSuccess()) {
   Log.i(TAG, "There was a problem inserting the session: "
     + insertStatus.getStatusMessage());
```

Comment: It would help if you post the important part of your source code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have solved this issue by replacing ".setDataType(DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT)" with ".setDataType(DataType.TYPE_SPEED)" and I had to add a new permission: "addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_LOCATION_READ_WRITE))"

Answer (score 0):

Your not giving much to go on but there has been a change to the Authentication.  See the [Announcement one the Google Fit developers G+ page](https://plus.google.com/u/0/105097205330899168606/posts/CGZj3eySxR2)

Comment: Thanks, the Fitness API was set up as described here: https://developers.google.com/fit/android/get-started#step_3_enable_the_fitness_api

Comment: I have tested the issue with production and debug build. I have created a test application and a separate project for it on Google API Console. The code stopped working a few weeks ago.